# knockoutjs : why doesnt my jquery get function fire the callback when my request is done

Tags: knockout.js

I have this button which when i click calls a knockout function which calls another jquery get function, but i noticed that the jquery get function get called and is exectuted but at the end of the execution the call back is not fired. why ?

this is my code

the button that fires it ?

```
 <li class="online" data-bind="click:$parent.startChat" >
```

the startchat method :

```
onlineFriends.startChat = function(friend) {


    onlineFriends.presentChat().id(friend.id());

    onlineFriends.presentChat().username(friend.userName());

    onlineFriends.presentChat().img(friend.picture());

    onlineFriends.presentChat().messages([]);

    onlineFriends.presentChat().messages(friend.messages());

    onlineFriends.loadMessages(friend.id(),1);

};
```

and finally the load message method :

```
onlineFriends.loadMessages = function(id,page) {

    $.get("http://localhost:8080/dashboard/message/" + id  + "/" + (page - 1), function(data, status){


        alert('happy');

    });

};
```

i put an alert in the call back, but it doesn't get fired and the get request returned successful from the server.

Comment: Are you sure it's `loadMessages` that initiates the successful `get`? Put a breakpoint before `$.get` and one inside the success callback. You should hit both.

Comment: @user3297291 yeah, i feel the problem was from the server, i had a stackoverflow